# Как в JS через prompt сделать проверку на введение математических операторов?

Tags: javascript

```
const mathOperator = prompt('Введите математическое действие');

if (mathOperator != '+' || mathOperator != '-' || mathOperator != '*' || mathOperator !='/') {
console.log('Программа не поддерживает такую операцию');
};
```

Comment: const p = prompt('Введите математическое действие');
var mas = ["-","+","=","/","*",];
if(mas.includes(p)) alert("Нельзя")

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что условие выполняется если `mathOperator` не равен любому из этих вариантов, поэтому стоит заменить `или ||` на `и &&`.

```
if (mathOperator != '+' && mathOperator != '-' && mathOperator != '*' && mathOperator !='/') {
  console.log('Программа не поддерживает такую операцию');
};
```